# jQuery .each dimension drill down

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have code that gets and parses data in a JSON array.  It's supposed to do it for each array entry, but it's only doing it for the first.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function (key, value){
            var mlsnum = value[1];
            var address = value[5] + ' ' + value[6] + ' ' + value[7];
            var city = value[9];
            var state = value[10];
            var zip = value[11];
            var county = value[12];
            var price = value[13];
            var sqft = value[17];
            var yrblt = value[22];
            var bdrms = value[14];
            var baths = value[15];
            $('#test').html(
                '<div class="listing_single">' +
                    '<div class="listing_img"><a href="http://mgoode.com/index.php?option=com_mls&view=mls&mlsnum=' + mlsnum + '"><img class="imgt" src="http://www.universaldynamicmedia.com/sandbox/Images/' + mlsnum + '/HQPhoto-' + mlsnum + '-1.jpeg" /></a></div>' +
                    '<div class="listing_data">' +
                    '<div class="listing_single_address "><a class="address_link" href="http://mgoode.com/index.php?option=com_mls&view=mls&mlsnum=' + mlsnum + '">' + address + '</a></div>' +
                    '<div class="listing_single_city">' + city + ', ' + state + ' ' + zip + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="listing_single_data_spec"><span class="listing_single_price">' + price + '</span>|<span class="data_small">SqFt: ' +  sqft + '</span>|<span class="data_small">Year Built: ' + yrblt + '</span>|<span class="data_small"> Bedrooms: ' + bdrms + '</span>|<span class="data_small"> Baths: ' + baths + '</span></div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '<div class="clear"></div></div>'
            );   
        });
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('There was an error loading your request.  <br />Please try again later.');
    }
});
```

The array is structured in 3-Dimensions...

```
{ "0" : [
    { "0" : [
        { "0" : "data1", "1" : "data2"}]}
    { "1" : [
        { "0" : "data1", "1" : "data2"}]}
]}
```

I figure it's only pulling data for `.each` first dimension item, for which there is only one.  I think I need to drill down the `.each` function into the second dimension, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: will you please add the json data also ?

Comment: You really shouldn't transfer each object as an array. It's a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I might agree with you if I know what that meant.  :/  It's an array returned from a mySQL query and then JSON encoded with PHP.  I don't feel like I have a lot of control over how it's returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just nest the jquery each statements? If I understand correctly:

```
 $.each(data, function(key, value) {

        $.each(value[key], function(key2, value2) {

            $.each(value2[key2], function(key3, value3){

                // etc.

            });

        });

    });
```

Comment: It still only shows one entry.  It's like it's not running through the second dimension, it's parsing the data for the 1st, but it's pulled the data from the 3rd.

Comment: I feel liked it needs to be `data.something` to get down to the next level of the JSON array. in the `.each` function.  I just can't figure out what.

Comment: If your data is an array filled with other arrays, then my code SHOULD work.. If you log value in the first each-statement, what does it print exactly?